# How can I get wvdial to run from /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, debian, mobile-broadband, wvdial

I am using wvdial to connect to a mobile network (I have a usb modem) and it works fine. However, I wanted to automate the connection a bit (currently I am running wvdial every time I want to connect). I was wandering if there is a way to add this network to `/etc/network/interfaces` (in a truly Debian way) to have it connect on startup and/or whenever I connect my modem.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 17):

Add to `/etc/network/interfaces` something like

```
auto ppp0
iface ppp0 inet wvdial
```

(tested on Ubuntu Lucid)

Comment: On Debian wheezy works too

Answer (score 2):

You need to integrate `wvdial` with the `ifupdown` system. If you want a full shell-based solution start with [The alternative PPP connection with wvdialconf](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/reference/ch05.en.html#_the_alternative_ppp_connection_with_wvdialconf). But note that Debian [recommends](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/reference/ch05.en.html#_the_modern_network_configuration_for_desktop) using graphical tools like the NetworkManager for configuring network connections on GUI-based desktops.

PS: That should normally be a comment but I don't have permissions to comment yet :)

Comment: Regarding GUI-based tools, I am using KDE and KNetworkManager just doesn't work :(

Comment: @Grzenio What do you mean by "just doesn't work"? I remember that it was very easy to create a new mobile broadband connection using the GNOME NetworkManager and set it to auto-connect. It should be similar in KNetworkManager.

Answer (score 0):

Try the *Auto Reconnect* feature of wvdial described in [wvdial.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/wvdial.conf).
This option is "on" by default, so might just not work in your case.

It it does not work for you, disable it and use instead this script from [ArchWiki Wvdial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wvdial#Auto_Reconnect) :

> If wvdial randomly drops connection you can use script below.
>
> ```
> #! /bin/bash
> (
>    while : ; do
>        wvdial
>        sleep 10
>    done
> ) &
> ```

Comment: Hi, I found this answer in another question here - it doesn't work. The problem is, sometimes the PPPD process dies, but, wvdial stays up - so, this script won't fire as wvdial can't run twice

Comment: @WilliamHilsum: If pppd is started from `/etc/inittab`, for example by `s1:23:respawn:/usr/sbin/pppd /dev/ttyS1 115200`, it will be restarted when it dies. The above script is supposed to fail and keep failing when wvdial is already running.

Answer (score 0):

To run *wvdial* with *boucle*, you can use this script and you can stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
#!/bin/bash     
i=1
while [ $i -le 10 ];
        wvdial 
        sleep 10
      $i
let $[ i+=1 ] 
done
```

Comment: This is extremely similar to @harrymc's answer. Are you able to go into a little more detail on what is different with your script and why it would work better? Please take a look at [answer] and take our [tour] to improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to fix this is having a [wvdial daemon](https://codehumble.wordpress.com/2020/04/14/how-to-reliably-connect-a-3g-mobile-broadband-usb-modem-to-linux-raspberry-pi-with-wvdial/) to keep the connection from disconnecting.